# Print contents of array modified in function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In my `main()` function I have declared an `array` of type `int` with the numbers 1 to 10. I then have two other functions of type `int*` that take this array and its size as parameters, perform some operations, and each returns a pointer to the new array. **Where I'm having issues is with a third function that prints the contents of the array**.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE_OF_ARRAY = 10;

int main() {

    int array[SIZE_OF_ARRAY] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    int *ptr1 = 0;
    ptr1 = function1(array, SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
    print(array, SIZE_OF_ARRAY);

    cout << endl;

    int *ptr2 = 0;
    ptr2 = function2(array, SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
    print(array, SIZE_OF_ARRAY);

    return 0;
}

void print(int array[], const int SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (SIZE_OF_ARRAY * 2); i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
}

int* function1(int array[], const int SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
{
    int *ptr = new int[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];

    // Do stuff.

    return ptr;
}

int* function2(int array[], const int SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
{
    int *ptr2 = new int[SIZE_OF_ARRAY * 2];

    // Create new array double in size, and set contents of ptr2 
    // to the contents of array. Then initialize the rest to 0.

    return ptr2;
}
```

As expected here, the result of calling the `print()` function twice is something like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 465738691 -989855001 1483324368 32767 -1944382035 32767 0 0 1 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 465738691 -989855001 1483324368 32767 -1944382035 32767 0 0 1 0
```

But I want the result to be like this instead:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can I accomplish this? (Note that for this assignment I'm using C++98). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Returning `new`'d allocations from functions is just asking for memory leaks. You should use vectors, or as the size is constant, regular arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`new int[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]` allocates memory, but doesn't assign values to the array elements. What you are seeing is what was in that memory when it got allocated for the array. You can change your `function2` to assign zeroes to array elements, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to print different number of elements on the two calls to `print`, so you should not delegate deciding whether to multiply the size by two to the `print`, but rather do it on the calling side. Change the `print` function to only iterate up to `SIZE_OF_ARRAY`, and change the two places where you call it to:

```
print(ptr1, SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
```

and

```
print(ptr2, SIZE_OF_ARRAY * 2);
```

correspondingly.

Now, I assume that your second function does assign values to all 20 elements, but if it does not, the ones to which it did not assign values would continue containing garbage. To get around it, just initialize them at the beginning of the second function:

```
int *ptr2 = new int[SIZE_OF_ARRAY * 2];
for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY * 2; ++ i) ptr2[i] = 0;
```

With these two changes you should get the desired behavior.

Also, if you allocate something with `new[]`, you need to delete it with `delete[]`, otherwise you get a memory leak. Add these two lines at the end of `main`:

```
delete[] ptr1;
delete[] ptr2;
```

Note, that using `delete` instead of `delete[]` would be wrong in this case. If something is allocated as an array, it **must** be deleted as an array.